# How to prevent Elasticsearch inserting date type documents as UTC timezone while indexing

Tags: java, datetime, elasticsearch

I'm using below code to insert some documents in elasticsearch index. But when inserting in the es the time is coming as UTC format rather than original GMT+5:30Z format. Where as the Sysout before indexing is giving me correct format as  **2014-08-11T18:23:13.447+05:30** . I want the original timestamp for analytics purpose. Please let me know how to keep the orizinal time format in document

```
public static IndexResponse addDocumentsQuota(Client client, String index,
        String type, String categoryName) {

     IndexResponse indexResponse = null;
     DateTime date = new DateTime();
     System.out.println(date);
     try {
        indexResponse = client.prepareIndex(index, type)
                                     .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                                                .startObject()
                                                .field("@timestamp", date)
                                                .field("category_name", categoryName)
                                                .field("alert_message", "alert message")
                                                .field("creation_time", date)
                                                .endObject())
                                                .execute()
                                                .actionGet();
    } catch (ElasticsearchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return indexResponse;
}
```

After indexing:

```
"_source": {
               "@timestamp": "2014-08-11T11:57:59.839Z",
               "category_name": "newCat1",
               "alert_message": "alert message",
               "creation_time": "2014-08-11T11:57:59.852Z"
            }
```

Thanks,
Subhadip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain specific date formatting in your `_source` document, you'll need to pass the date into the `.field` as a `String`.  Since you've said the `System.out.println()` prints it in the format you want, you simply need to change to:

```
...
   .field("creation_time", date.toString())
...
```

In any event internally, ES stores the timestamps in GMT.

Comment: Hi Alcanzar- tried that, but not working. Indexing with GMT time only

Comment: You are mistaken.  I ran modded code against my ES cluster and when I fetch the document from my cluster I get this `"_source" : {"@timestamp":"2014-08-14T13:42:42.227Z","category_name":"bob","alert_message":"alert message","creation_time":"2014-08-14T08:42:42.227-05:00"}`.  Note the creation_time is in my local time zone and the `_mapping` shows it as a date: `{"test":{"mappings":{"test":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"alert_message":{"type":"string"},"category_name":{"type":"string"},"creation_time":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"}}}}}}`

Comment: Hi Alcanzer - I now tried with sending the datetime as a string and it worked. Great!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the date format in the mapping, i.e.

```
 {
     "yourType": {
         "properties": {
             "creation_time": {
                 "type": "date",
                 "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dan- I tried the format, but still the time is getting inserted as GMT time only.

Comment: Did you re-index the data with the new mapping? I did a simple example, I just added the mapping above to a test index and indexed your date. When I did a search for the document I could see it indexed the date as is '2014-08-11T18:23:13.447+05:30'. Try a with a simple example.

Comment: I tried sending the DateTime object as a string only without any mapping format and it worked, guess ES is looking for string as timestamp. Thanks for your help.